# How to store and use the rules in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need to apply some rules to my program and I was wondering how I can store and use the rules in Mongodb?

Comment: you'll need to include some details about your app, and more importantly, the laguage(s) and libraries you are using. But a general answer to this question is "on the application side"

Comment: I am doing a mapping between two systems. I use MongoDB and C#(Auto Mapper library to do the mapping). I need to use some rules to map a field of one C# object to multiple fields of another C# object. Does that mean that I have to include the rules in my C# program?

Comment: yes, if by "rules" you mean constraints on your data, they will mostly be application-side. However, you can (and should) create indexes on your MongoDB collections that include uniqueness constraints.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores data in BSON objects (pretty much JSON, similar to C# Dictionaries in that they use a Key/Value syntax where every key is unique to it's scope). So all you have to do is store the data in a form that you can read later. For example, if have a C# object Circle that you need to create based on data stored in MongoDB a document in your database could look like this:

```
{
 type : Circle,
 members : {
  radius : 5,
  filled : false,
  color : blue
 },
 _id:[generated by mongodb],
 ... any other data you need to create a new instance of a Circle from your DB
}
```

If you're familiar with working with JSON objects then this should be a breeze. As far as your "rules" go, this should work just fine. Just use the rule name for your "key".